# Waiting for the result returned by an activity inside the method that called startActivityForResult

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I have a method that calls startActivityForResult to start another activity that opens camera and returns url of the picture captured. The method that calls startActivityForResult returns url to some other function. But when the camera activity is opened the method opening it finishes and result is obtained in onActivityResult callback. I just want to get the result where Camera activity is started. Is there a way to achieve this. I mean by making the method wait until the value is obtained in the onActivityResult callback?

Comment: `The method that calls startActivityForResult returns url to some other function.` What kind of url? And what does it have to do with the fact that you just started an activity?

Comment: It is unclear why you want such a construct. And the user can cancel the operation too. What would it bring you? How would you transfer the url obtained in onActivityResult to your method?

Comment: Actually I am calling a method channel function from flutter that starts the activity and that needs to return the value to flutter from the same method channel function only

Comment: In flutter you can call Native java functions by creating a method channel and the called function can return the results to flutter as well

Comment: I started native cameraX activity from flutter and I want to retrieve the url when the picture is clicked. My flutter logic depends on the url of image captured